# TPM 2.0 causes high temps and boot fail

Tags: security, motherboard, bios, power-supply, tpm

So I just bought a TPM 2.0 module for my second PC which I mainly use for video editing and 3D animation, so it's a fairly high-end machine.
I installed the TPM module on the motherboard, and turned it on.
At first it kept "power cycling", the lights and fans turn on for a second, then turn off, and this happens until I switch off the PSU or otherwise unplug it. I think this might've been over-voltage protection kicking in.
I managed to get to BIOS, which recorded my CPU temp as 126C (only briefly, I turned it off soon after), and this is a water cooled PC in a cool room. Motherboard temp was recorded as 0C for some reason.
BIOS said that it found a TPM 2.0 module and functioned fine otherwise.
I stupidly decided to try and touch the TPM module, which was really hot, I nearly burnt my finger.
Once I quit out of BIOS, the boot screen only had a blinking insert cursor.

Once I removed the module, my PC booted fine and the temps are normal.

I suspect this is either a faulty motherboard connector or a faulty module.

Any ideas as to what went wrong? Should I return the TPM?

Comment: Did you get the orientation right?

Comment: What Mainboard and what TPM module do you use? TMP modules are not standardized (usually a TPM should be soldered onto the Mainboard), hence you need the exact matching model for your board.

Comment: Yeah, the orientation is fine, it only goes one way, because it's a 14 pin module, where one pin is empty. Mobo is MSI Z170A Gaming Pro Carbon, it's a motherboard from my last gaming rig. I have never heard about TPMs being soldered on, because then why provide a header?